# GhostScript was not found with extrafont

Tags: r, macos, ghostscript, apple-m1, extrafont

I'm using an M1, Big Sur Macbook. I need to embed the fonts of a number of pdfs that include plots from `ggplot2`.

However, when I run the `embed_fonts()` function, it returns the following error message: `GhostScript was not found`

With `Homebrew`, I installed `Ghostscript`. I have also reinstalled `extrafont` and `extrafontdb`, restarted `RStudio`, and then run `font_import()` and `loadfonts()` again. None of this solves the error message.

Have you experienced this problem? I wonder if it's because of the change to the M1's Apple Silicon?

I have also switched from using `bash` to `zsh` in my terminal. Could that have affected this?

**A reprex:**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)

(plot <- ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
    geom_point())

ggsave("test_plot.pdf", plot)

embed_fonts(file = "test_plot.pdf", outfile = "test_plot_embedded.pdf")
```

I found the following two answers that seem related, but I'm unsure how to implement them:

[How to fix "Unable to find GhostScript executable to run checks on size reduction" error upon package check in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197603/how-to-fix-unable-to-find-ghostscript-executable-to-run-checks-on-size-reductio)

[R does not recognize GhostScript to embed eps plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971473/r-does-not-recognize-ghostscript-to-embed-eps-plots)

Comment: Well, do you have R_GSCMD defined or not?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm trying to find the path to define it and how to define it. I assume I define the path using Sys.setenv(R_GSCMD = "path/to/gs")

Comment: Problem disappears when installing Ghostscript directly from https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was solved when I installed Ghostscript directly https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/ (Ghostscript 9.54.0)

It appears there was, at least on my end, an issue using `homebrew install ghostscript`. When I ran that in Terminal, everything appeared to be fine. No error messages.